# How to concatenate base64 with type in src

Tags: javascript, angular

```
<div *ngFor="let el of list">
        <img [src]='el.photo'
</div>
```

Api retturn
el.photo = '/9j/2wBDAAMCAgMCAgMDAw......'

and i want concatante with

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,
```

something like that

```
<img [src]='data:image/jpeg;base64, + 'el.photo''>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display Base64 images in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499633/how-to-display-base64-images-in-html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstable it would be

```
<img [src]="'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + el.photo">
```

But I suppose it was only a mistake. However I would suggest you to make concatenations like this in controller and not in view (as a part of good coding practices). You can eg. make a function which would return concatenated string in controller:

```
function getBase64ImageSrc(photo) {
  return 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + photo;
}
```

And then use this function in view:

```
<img [src]="getBase64ImageSrc(el.photo)">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
<img src={{'data:image/jpeg;base64, + el.photo}}>
```